# Discord.js moving person to random VoiceChannel hel

Tags: javascript

everyting work but bot cant move person to random voice channel
or do new code for me pls i can give u all details

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isButton()) return;
    if (interaction.customId === 'move_member') {
        const userId = interaction.user.id;
        const guild = interaction.guild;
        const member = guild.members.cache.get(userId);
        if (member.voice && member.voice.channel) {
            try {
                const randomChannel = await moveMemberToRandomChannel(member);
                if (randomChannel) {
                    interaction.update({ content: `คุณได้ถูกย้ายไปยัง ${randomChannel.name}`, components: [] });
                } else {
                    interaction.reply('ไม่สามารถย้ายไปยังห้องได้');
                }
            } catch (error) {
                interaction.reply(error.message);
            }
        } else {
            interaction.reply('คุณต้องเชื่อมต่อกับห้องเสียงเพื่อให้บอทย้ายคุณไปยังห้องสุ่มได้');
        }
    }
});
```